# Please help me on this problem on Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, proof-explanation

Given, $2\sin^2 \theta = \sqrt{3}$.  Prove that $\ \theta = 30^{\circ}$

I have been trying this problem since yesterday by using identities but i could not reach to the conclusion as desired. Please guide me on how to solve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: If $\theta=30^\circ$, then $2\sin^2\theta=1/2$.

Comment: Am sure there's a mistake in your question. If $\theta=30$ then $2\sin^2\theta$ is not $\sqrt {3} $

Comment: $\sin 2\theta$ instead of $sin^2 \theta$?

Comment: Maybe please try with sin2 theeta

Comment: Even if $2\sin(2\theta) = \sqrt{3}$ was intended, there are infinitely many solutions unless there is an unstated restriction on the values that $\theta$ can assume.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you meant:
$$ 2\sin(2\theta) = \sqrt{3} $$
Do the following algebra:
$$ \sin(2\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\;\;\;\implies\;\;\; 2\theta=\arcsin(\sqrt{3}/2)\;\;\;\implies\;\;\; \theta=\frac{1}{2}\arcsin\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right) = \frac{\pi}{6} $$
Notice that $\theta=\pi/6=30^\circ$.

Perhaps this is easiest to understand by looking at [the special values for sine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine#Special_values), from which one sees  that: 
$$ \sin(\pi/3)=\sqrt{3}/2\;\;\;\implies\;\;\;\arcsin(\sqrt{3}/2) = \pi/3 $$

Of course, because $\sin(\theta)$ is periodic, there are an infinite number of solutions to the equation; however, this is the smallest positive one.

Comment: There are two solutions in the interval $[0, 2\pi]$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Good point; fixed.